Testing mogodb users service with nestjs
I'm new to here stackoverflow and I have one problem with testing my nestjs users service.
I just started learning nestjs so I'm not sure how to solve this issue.
This is my user service test code.
beforeEach(async () => {
    userModelMock = {
      exists: jest.fn(),
      findOne: jest.fn(),
      create: jest.fn(),
      // exec: jest.fn(),
      prototype: {
        save: jest.fn(),
      },
    };

    userModelMock = {
      exists: jest.fn(),
      prototype: {
        save: jest.fn(),
      },
      new: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
      })),
    };

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        {
          provide: getModelToken('User'),
          useValue: userModelMock,
        },
        {
          provide: RabbitmqService,
          useValue: {},
        },
        {
          provide: MailsService,
          useValue: {},
        },
        {
          provide: ImagesService,
          useValue: {},
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });

  it('should create a new user', async () => {
    const userDto = {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      first_name: 'John',
      last_name: 'Doe',
      avatar: 'avatar-url',
    };

    userModelMock.exists.mockResolvedValue(false);

    const result = await service.create(userDto);

    expect(result.statusCode).toBe(httpStatusText(HttpStatus.OK));
    expect(userModelMock.exists).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ email: userDto.email });
    expect(userModelMock.new).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userDto);
    expect(userModelMock.prototype.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

and this is my service file.
constructor(
    @InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
    private readonly rabbitMQService: RabbitmqService,
    private readonly mailService: MailsService,
    private readonly imageService: ImagesService,
  ) {}

  async create(userDto: UserDto) {
    try {
      const newUser = new this.userModel(userDto);
      const isDuplicatedEmail = await this.userModel.exists({
        email: newUser.email,
      });

      if (isDuplicatedEmail) {
        return errorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, 'email already exists');
      }

      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      const userName = `${newUser.first_name} ${newUser.last_name}`;

      await Promise.all([
        this.mailService.sendCreationEmail(newUser.email, userName),
        this.rabbitMQService.sendAccountCreationEvent(
          'user-created',
          newUser.email,
          newUser.toJSON(),
        ),
      ]);
      return successResponse('Saved user info in db successfully!', {
        newUser: savedUser,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Saving user info in db failed! [${error}]`);
      return errorResponse(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, 'DB is down');
    }
  }

But when I run the test I got this error:
TypeError: this.userModel is not a constructor.
Please help me.
I tried to solve this issue with this article but I'm not sure how to do it.
Testing mongoose models with NestJS
